# Reference for maps whose pushouts are also homotopy pushouts

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, homotopy-limits

Consider a category C with weak equivalences, e.g., a model category.

For the purposes of this question, let's say that a morphism f in C is an *i-cofibration* if any pushout (alias cobase change) along f is also a homotopy pushout.

This notion is closely related to that of h-cofibration (alias flat map, cosharp map, left proper map, W-cofibration, cofibrillation, weak cofibration,
see the [terminological discussion at n-Café](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/07/pullbacks_that_preserve_weak_e.html)).
The latter is defined as a morphism f: A→B for which the induced cobase change functor f_*: A/C→B/C preserves weak equivalences.

If C is a left proper model category, then i-cofibrations coincide with h-cofibrations and contain cofibrations,
see, for example, Lemma 1.2 and Proposition 1.5.(i,ii) in Batanin and Berger's “Homotopy theory for algebras over polynomial monads” ([arXiv:1305.0086](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0086)).

If C is not left proper, then i-cofibrations do not necessarily coincide with h-cofibrations.

Has the notion of i-cofibration been studied before?  Does it have a name of its own?
Any references on this matter will be appreciated.

Motivation for this question comes from a desire to study (homotopy) pushouts in model categories of algebras over operads, which are rarely left proper.

Comment: The same motivation applies to calculating homotopy pushouts of operads themselves.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole: Of course!  The category of operads itself is the category of algebras over a certain colored operad (the “operad of operads”), so this example is covered by the main post.  The example that I have in mind is that of enriched categories in enriched categories, i.e., higher enriched categories.